# Excel List Comparative

Tags: excel, list, compare, comparable

I need some help again. I have two lists I created in excel using the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(Schedule!$A$2,MATCH(ROW()-224,Wednesday!BV:BV,0)-3,0),"")
```

Using this formula I created two lists from the Wednesday Sheet and Friday Sheet. I found a way from other posts to test if someone is on both lists using this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B$190:B$220,B225),B225,"")
```

Now I need a way to test if someone is on one list but not the either. If it is lets say List A and not in List B, then print the Value from A that wasn't in B and visa versa. If this is confusing just say something and I will try to explain again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where your data is, but you could try searching, for each value in each list, in the other list, maybe with something of the following nature:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B190,Friday!$B$190:$B$220,1,0)),"here",)
```

the idea being to detect the error that should arise where the search term is not found, then use that to trigger a response (here `here`).

Then repeat the process on the alternative sheet with `Friday` replaced by `Wednesday`.

In both cases the ranges may require adjustment for your situation.